# Wordpress "redirected too many times" problem but only homepage url

Tags: php, wordpress, web, cloudflare

everyone I recently migrated my website from one host to another host (ionos to plesk vps), using all one migration plugin website migrated successfully but the website homepage URL shows "too many redirects"` the problem is the only homepage url is not working specifically but all my website pages, url, posts, and WordPress dashboard loading correctly.

I am using Cloudflare for dns & ssl, elementor, woocommerce, etc on my website, When I shift my website back to the old IP (host), the website works but in the new host website homepage url is not working.

the website only works when I disable the Cloudflare proxy so that means the problem is coming from the Cloudflare

**fix I try:**

1. Changing the site url
2. Changing Cloudflare ssl mode to full, flexible, and full strict
3. creating a default `.htaccess` file
4. I try to open the website in incognito mode and another device
5. disabling the plugins etc (but nothing working for me)

If anyone can help me with this it would be greatly appreciated